# SSIS prevent warnings from propagating

Tags: sql-server, ssis, warnings, stoppropagation, propagation

I've got a script running in a Foreach Loop Container, inside my package's Control Flow.

In the script, I am throwing a warning, then exiting with success

```
Dts.Events.FireWarning(-1, "", "warning message here", "", 0);

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

I've set the system Propagate variables all to false.

Also tried setting the Package property DisableEventHandlers to True.

[image: Variables]

However, duplicate warning messages are still being thrown in the order of:

1. Script
2. Foreach Loop Container
3. Package

I could possibly log each incident as Information instead of a Warning... but I dont want to log all Information.  Logging all Warnings is much more realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an OnWarning Event Handler for your script task.  The event handler does not need any tasks of its own, but it does need its system variable Propagate set to False.

Comment: That did it, thank you!  It seems I had to go through every Task in my Package and modify it's Event Handler property.  Is there any way to do a global change?  I tried setting the Package's OnWarning Event Handler but it had no affect without changing each task individually.

Comment: I don't think there is a global way to set it, but I often use Sequence Containers to accomplish this, so that any error in any task inside the Sequence Container would not propagate outside of it.